# Issue with local Ubuntu mirror

Tags: apt-mirror

I have a local Ubuntu mirror set up but I seem to be missing the "installer-amd64" directory and all its files. I need to be able to mirror the netboot installer files to my local mirror.  Here is a snippet from my mirror.list.

```
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main main/debian-installer restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

It seems like the installer files may be treated differently than the package files.  I tried the following line as well in my mirror.list but had no luck.

```
deb-installer-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise netboot cdrom
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Update - I added the following to my postmirror.sh script as a work around:

```
rsync --recursive --times --links --hard-links --delete --delete-after rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-amd64/ /var/www/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-amd64/
rsync --recursive --times --links --hard-links --delete --delete-after rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-i386/ /var/www/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-i386/
```